# How to make a typoscript level 2 menu only?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to generate with typoscript a menu that only shows the level 2 subpages. this are the pages just below the main pages under the root domain. Of course the subpages of the active main page needs to be generated. Can someone help, I'm stuck for 2 days?

Meaning the output should be as simple as:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="subpage1">name subpage</a></li>
   <li><a href="subpage2">name other subpage</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your inner page template create another partial file in your template Partial folder.

```
<f:render section="InnerLeftNavigation" partial="InnerLeftNavigation" optional="TRUE" arguments="{_all}"/>
```

And add below code:

http://pastebin.com/EBUkK2D8

And for `entryLevel="{v:variable.typoscript(path: 'lib.menu.subOfSub.entryLevel')}"`

Assign value with treelevel condition in typoscript file.

http://pastebin.com/DZGSuEcj